# C# run public void functions in loop

Tags: c#

I have list of public void function that get one parameter to execute and I want to use loop to do it,
I do not know how to do this, can you advise me?
I thought to insert the names of mt functions to arr and than run in loop 
something like this

```
string[] s1 = new string[3] {"func1", "func2", "func3"};
for(int i=0;i<s1.lengh;i++)
```

here I want to call the function ... how can I do it?

Do you have better offer?
Thanks.

Comment: Try `List<Action<T>>()`. Edit: yeah, `T`.

Comment: rather List<Action<T>>() :-)

Comment: What is the type of the argument?

Comment: @CodeCaster OP said "void function that get one parameter". Use `Action<T>`.

Comment: Can you give me short example to use it?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass functions as parameters / arguments by the use of delegates:

```
Action<T> action1 = func1;
Action<T> action2 = func2;
```

where T is the type of the parameter (e.g. int, string)

You can then run these referenced functions by calling

```
action1(t);
action2(t);
```

where t is the parameter for your function.

To make this example useful, consider creating a list of actions:

```
List<Action<T>> actions = new List<Action<T>>();
actions.Add(action1); actions.Add(action2);
foreach (Action<T> action in actions)
{
    var t = param; // Replace param with the input parameter
    action(t);
}
```

Of course, you must also have

```
using System;
```

at the top of your code file to reference Action.

See also the MSDN documentation on the Action delegate: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx

Comment: `= func[12];`, rather? (No call)

Comment: OP said "void function that get one parameter". Use `Action<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first option is to use delegates (assuming the argument is an integer):

```
var s1 = new Action<int>[3] { a => func1(a), a => func2(a), a => func3(a) }; // without quotes it creates a function pointer
for(int i=0;i<s1.Length;i++)
   s1[i](parameter); // call the delegate
```

If you do not know the function names at compile time, use reflection to call the method:

```
var s1 = new string[3] {"func1", "func2", "func3"};
for(int i=0;i<s1.Length;i++)
   this.GetType().GetMethod(s1[i]).Invoke(this, new object[] { parameter });
```

Note the `this.GetType()` in the second sample - if the methods are defined on another type you will most probably use `typeof(OtherType)` instead.

Comment: Action is just a type that allows you to store a function call as a pointer to be called later.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx). For example, to invoke a method that takes one parameter and returns no value (i.e. returns `void`), use the [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx) delegate. Assuming that you want them all to accept the same parameter type, it would look a bit like this:

```
public void Action1(int x) { ... }
public void Action2(int x) { ... }
public void Action3(int x) { ... }

...

Action<int>[] actions = new Action<int>[] { Action1, Action2, Action3 }
for (int i = 0; i < actions.Length; i++)
{
    actions[i](i);  // Invoke the delegate with (...)
}
```

**Further Reading**

- [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are wanting to do could be accomplished via a collection of actions.

Assuming the type of parameter for each function is integer, here's how that could look:

```
List<Action<int>> functions = new List<Action<int>> {func1, func2, func3};

int i = 5;
foreach (Action<int> f in functions)
{
     f(i);
}
```

**EDIT**: updated per updated OP that specifies the looping should only be over each of the functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new List<Action<MyParameterType>>() {func1, func2, func3};
foreach(var func in list)
{
   func(someValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] s1 = new string[3] {"func1", "func2", "func3"};
for(int i=0;i<s1.lengh;i++)

List<string, Func<string>> functionList = new List<string, Func<string>>();
functionList.Add(s1[0], ()=>{return "You called func1!";});
functionList.Add(s1[1], ()=>{return "You called func2!";});
functionList.Add(s1[2], ()=>{return "You called func3!";});

for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
{
  string retVal = functionList[s1[i]].Invoke();
}
```